# How to pull IMG SRC from one HTML tag into another?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school project and I'm wondering if this is possible:

In one div, I've defined an `<img>`, which will display.

In the second div, I want the `img src` to come from the first div.

Is it possible to do this? Preferably without anything besides css/html.

Comment: You will need JS for that. Then it's pretty straightforward

Comment: I don't think that's possible without `JavaScript`.

Comment: You can't directly reference it. You would need JavaScript for that. What I'm about to suggest you should only do for presentational imagery like an icon or the background for a button. You could set up a CSS class that uses the image as the `background-image`.  I would do this for regular photos.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind *a little* JS you can do it inline in your HTML. E.g.

```html
<img id="img1" src="http://cdn.obsidianportal.com/assets/50953/serenity19dc.png" /> 
   
<img id="img2" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" onload="this.src=document.getElementById('img1').src" />
```

Here the second image has intially just a placeholder image (1x1 gif) but on load it is replaced by SRC from the first image.

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript to copy the `src` attribute, but you can have two images while defining the URL in one place by defining a background image in CSS:

```css
.is-image {
  background: url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png') no-repeat;
  width: 538px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="is-image"></div>
<div class="is-image"></div>
```